# UIWebView doesn't load some link

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview, format

hello 
I'm trying to write an rss feed viewer for my iPhone. In my DetailView I have a UIWebView where I want to display specific link retrieved with the rss item.:

```
NSString* url = [data objectForKey:@"link"];
NSString *encodedUrl = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]; 
NSLog(@"Selected link:%@",url);
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl]];
[itemWebpage loadRequest:request];
[request release];
```

now,if the retrieved link is something like

```
www.shazaam.com
```

it works. But as soon as the link is something like:

```
http://www.shazam.com/music/web/track?id=41970148"
```

it doesn't. I suppose it's because of the parameter...but how can I fix the problem????

thanks a lot!

elos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is for when you want to put a string into a query variable.  You don't need to do it for entire URLs.  The question mark is being encoded when it shouldn't be, so you are getting a 404.  Don't encode the URL and you should be fine.